# Adding a column at a specific position using DBMS_REDEFINITION

Tags: oracle

Can anybody tell me how I can add a column to table at a specific position using the `DBMS_REDEFINITION` package from Oracle?

Comment: Please read this [Oracle description](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tables.htm#ADMIN01514) and come back with specific questions.

Comment: Can you expand your question by stating why it even matters what order the columns are in?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer: you cannot add column to a table at a specific position.

When you add new columns they always go after the existing columns. You have to re-create your table with new definition to place a column to a position you need.

You can however create views with columns positioned arbitrarily based on your existing table, and then query or update the table directly or through your newly created views (see the section ["About Views"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/views001.htm#i1007900) in Database Administrator's Guide). Though some restrictions may apply to the updatable views, join views in particular (see the section ["Updating a Join View"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/views001.htm#i1006232) in Database Administrator's Guide).

Comment: That is not entirely true - "re-creating" a table is part of the Package the OP is asking about, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tables.htm#ADMIN01514 . That Package helps with keeping the table accessible while redefining it...

Comment: @Yahia well it's true if you're using a simple "alter table ..." -- with DBMS_Redefinition you can do anything you want, but if the question is "how do I use DBMS_Redefinition" then it's rather too broad. I think Yasir's answer is worth upvoting because ultimately column order is irrelevant.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Agreed. No doubt there's an ORM that requires the order, or some other hideousness involved! Maybe some beautiful `SELECT * FROM ... ` :)